# Django, sending beautifulsoup parsed html via ajax gives is not JSON serializable error

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to parse html and trying to pass img elements via JsonResponse to the template.

My view:

```
def spider(request):

    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=cizre&biw=1438&bih=802&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu8any3vLJAhWBkywKHfEbAeoQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=_")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    images = soup.findAll("img")

    imagesDict = {}
    for i in range(len(images)):
        imagesDict[i] = images[i]

    return JsonResponse(imagesDict)
```

But i am getting this error:

```
TypeError at /spider/ <img alt="" height="23" onclick="(function(){var text_input_assistant_js='/textinputassistant/11/tr_tia.js';var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = text_input_assistant_js;(document.getElementById('xjsc')|| document.body).appendChild(s);})();" src="/textinputassistant/tia.png" style="padding-top:2px" width="27"/> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You cannot do that, because what BeautifulSoup `findAll` returns is a list of beautiful soup objects, but json is only a string. What information for those images are you trying to use for `JsonResponse`?

Comment: I am trying to send img tags as a string dictionary to the template ( via ajax ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, because what BeautifulSoup `findAll` returns is a list of beautiful soup objects, but `json` can only have plain types. That error in general says "what you are trying to serialize is not in json recognizable format". You can do:

```
def spider(request):
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=cizre&biw=1438&bih=802&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu8any3vLJAhWBkywKHfEbAeoQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=_")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    images = soup.findAll("img")
    imagesDict = {}
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        # convert object to string
        imagesDict[i] = str(image)
    return JsonResponse(imageDict)
```